# yocto image size gets increased with increase in partition size

Tags: yocto, yocto-wic

I am creating an empty partition for my yocto image file(.wic) by adding below line to `directdisk.wks`:

```
part /opt --use-uuid --fstype=ext4 --label user --align 1024 --size 1024
```

Able to create a partition but the image size gets increased i.e. `image size + partition size`. let's say, I have created empty `/opt` partition of `1GB`, then `1.53 GB(initial image size) + 1 GB(/opt) = 2.53 GB(new image size)`. My concern is what happens with a 128 GB SSD allocated fully with partitions. Will the image size be 128 GB?

> Is there a way to generate `.wic` unaffected with empty partition
>   size?

Comment: you can generate sparse wic (wic.bmap) image which would compress empty sections. and then use bmap-tools to flash the image. like here https://github.com/riscv/meta-riscv#sparse-image-creation

Comment: do we have bmap-tools alternative for windows?

Comment: @Khem - Size of `.direct` image generated by `wic directdisk -e core-image-sato` is only reduced by half of the partition size(~500 MB) though I have created 1GB partition. an thoughts on this?

Comment: @md.jamal You can use balena etcher to flash an image with a bmap file if you package it all in a zip file.  cp image.{wic,img}; cp image.{wic,img}.bmap; md5sum image.img > image.img.md5; zip image.img.zip image.img*